# Cocoapods No Source Files After Install

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I did a straightforward pods install into an existing Xcode project. When I open the xcworspace file, all I see is:

[image: from xcworspace]

What I see in when I open xcodeproj is:

[image: from xcodeproj]

How can I fix this so I can see all my folders when opening xcworspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have both the project AND the workspace open in Xcode at the same time.

Go into Xcode, close both the workspace and the project, then only open the .xcworkspace file and you will be able to click the disclosure triangle next to the xcodeproj and list those files in the file IDE along the left side.